# How to run commands on multiple powershell windows

Tags: powershell

I have several powershell windows open where I need to run the same commands in all those windows . A way that I considered to do that was

```
Get-Process -Name 'Powershell'
```

and get the ID and parse the powershell commands to those PIDs

How can this be done? Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? If you simply want to run multiple commands in parallel, you can use jobs.

Comment: PowerShell actually has multiple ways to run work in parallel.  The one I've recently been playing with is a module you can download called "SplitPipeline".  I was able to send it a list of 38 computers, had a limit of doing 10 at a time, the process takes around 3 minutes on each computer, all computers were done I think somewhere around 10 to 15 minutes (One at a time would have been over an hour and a half), and the results came back in on the pipeline.

Comment: @Darin In this case is the same computer but the commands would run on different powershell windows. By using the SplitPipeline module how could this be done?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala How could jobs be used in this situation. Can you provide an example?
Once I nedd to run Get-Process -Name 'Powershell' to get all the powershell processes PID running, how can jobs could be used here together so the commands to be placed on all the powershell windows open?

Comment: @vitr, I could see doing a windows form and having many instances of that form show up when ran from a single PowerShell window.  Or I could see writing a powershell script and run that same script on each window.  But I'm sorry, I can't get my mind around what you are trying to do and why it has to be done that way.

Comment: @vitr Why is it important that the commands run in existing processes? What is it you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @vitr, a non PowerShell solution would be to use a program like QuickMacros, https://www.quickmacros.com/, you can try it for free, but cost $60.  It gives you the ability to identify existing windows and send keystrokes to them.  It has a C style language - sort of, but he really did his own thing with it.  So there is a little bit of a learning curve, but he has fairly good documentation.  As for you typing in one windows, and having it happen in the other windows, maybe QuickMacros could do that, but that is outside the scope of anything I've ever done with it.